# MLX90614 and Micropython

Tags: sensors, esp32, i2c, micropython

I have a project that uses the DFRobot Gravity: I2C Non-contact IR Temperature Sensor (using the MLX90614-DCI chip). This sensor will be accessed by an ESP32 running Micropython.

Strangely, I keep getting 0xFFFF for any temperature readings (registers 0x06 and 0x07) for 10-15 attempts before getting the correct reading. I know this because I created a loop and the loop ends if I do not get a reading of 0XFFFF, which is around 10-15 times.

My wiring:

- I connected the sensor's SDA pin to the ESP32's pin 21.
- The sensor's SCL pin to the ESP32's pin 22.
- The sensor's ground pin is connected to the ESP32's ground pin.
- The sensor's VCC pin is connected to the ESP32's 3.3V pin.

In Micropython I am using the SoftI2C module to connect to the sensor. Below is the code snippet:

```
  from machine import SoftI2C, Pin
  import ustruct

  sda_pin = Pin(21)
  scl_pin = Pin(22)
  i2c = SoftI2C(scl=scl_pin, sda=sda_pin)
  data = ustruct.unpack('<H', i2c.readfrom_mem(0x5A, 0x06, 2))[0]
  # Data will be 0xFFFF for 10-15 times before returning the correct result
```

Any insights will be appreciated.

Thx

Comment: Why are you using SoftI2C instead of using the hardware I2C controller? The first thing I would try in debugging this would be to use hardware I2C.

Comment: I get a warning that I2C is deprecated and suggest to use SoftI2C.

Comment: It is definitely not deprecated. There's [a specific way of using defaults with it](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=9940) which is deprecated. I'd recommend trying this with hardware I2C.

Comment: Oh I see. The warning message is a little confusing. Thx @romkey . Change the code to use I2C, with id=1. Now, I am still getting an 0xFFFF value but interleave with a timeout exception: `OSError: [Errno 116] ETIMEDOUT`. Any insights are appreciate it.

Comment: The warning is definitely confusing :) Are you using pull-up resistors to 3.3V on SDA and SCL? I'm not sure if the DFRobot board has them (it probably does, but the timeout error makes me think there might be a wiring issue).

Comment: SDA and SCL are both using pull-up resistors, based on the board provided schematics: [SEN0206 Schematics](https://dfimg.dfrobot.com/nobody/wiki/238b0ef52f6f3a0fc460a6811219b240.pdf).

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have any better suggestions. It's possible DFRobot's tech support or forums might be able to help. I had a problem with one of their boards recently and their tech support people were actually really helpful).